# Rapheal Pie Chart Rendering Issue in IE 9

Tags: html, svg, internet-explorer-9, raphael, pie-chart

I have got an issue in IE9 like "SVG4601: SVG Path data has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed" while drawing pie chart in HTML5 page using Raphael JS and SVG. 
                            When I was drawing the svg path, since the  "d" attribute,
d="(path data)" as null, pie chart doesn't appears and showing a console error like "SVG4601: SVG Path data has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed".

The html content should be like this...

```
<path style="fill: #993333; stroke: #ffffff; stroke-width: 0;" fill="#993333" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" d="M261.5,86.4 A100,100,0,1,0,271.5,98.5"/>
```

But I'm getting in IE9..

```
<path style="fill: #993333; stroke: #ffffff; stroke-width: 0;" fill="#993333" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" d=""/>
```

Currently its perfectly working in IE8 and all other browsers.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I too found the same issue, any solutions to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have updated my Raphael library to V 2.10 and its working perfectly.

For IE8 development, please use svg path instead of circle tag

Comment: thanks! i solved ie9 in "svg path data has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed" error